# Search function on PHP/HTML page using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, post

**Description**: Trying to do a title search for videos within a PHP page with AJAX pagination.

**Problem**: "Search" button does not do anything when pressed. Instead, if I write something in "keywords" field and switch from page 1 to page 2 the date gets updated and shows videos with matching title. If I delete what I wrote in "keywords" field, and switch again between pages, the data gets updated. As mentioned, "Search" button does not work.

**Fix**: I would like to write in the text field and press "Search" button. The page should then update and show only the videos with the matching title.

**search.php**:

```
<!-- Testing the search -->
<p><b> Search all videos in database below: </b></p>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
        <input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" size="50" maxlength="64" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="loadData()" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**search_videos.js**:
* 'page' variable is used for pagination

```
...
function loadData(page){                   
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search_videos.php",
        data: { 'page': page, 'keywords': $('#keywords').val() },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            loading_hide();
            $("#container").html(msg);
        }
    });
}         
...
```

Update: Below is what I get, after I press 2nd page and then 1st page again.

[image]

POST results:
[image]

Raw results (sorry for bad formatting):

```
005<div class='data' style='margin-bottom:10px'><ul><a href="view.php?id=0"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a><li>Title: <b>Video 1</b></br> Uploaded by: user1</br>Date added: 13/07/2013</li></br></br><a href="view.php?id=1"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a><li>Title: <b>ghg</b></br> Uploaded by: cacamaca</br>Date added: 21 Jul 2013 16:03</li></br></br><a href="view.php?id=2"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a><li>Title: <b>s</b></br> Uploaded by: cacamaca</br>Date added: 21 Jul 2013 16:23</li></br></br><a href="view.php?id=3"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a><li>Title: <b>s</b></br> Uploaded by: cacamaca</br>Date added: 21 Jul 2013 16:24</li></br></br><a href="view.php?id=4"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a><li>Title: <b>dg</b></br> Uploaded by: gdfgdf</br>Date added: data azi</li></br></br></ul></div><div class='pagination'><ul><li class='inactive'>Previous</li><li p='1' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>1</li><li p='2' class='active'>2</li><li p='2' class='active'>Next</li>
```

This is what I get when I press search button now:

[image]

This is a bit long, the first part of the code should be relevant to the problem. Here is the code for:

search_videos.php :

```
<?php
if($_POST['page'])
{
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 5;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;

include"core/database/connect.php";

// Get the input of the selected video
$input = $_POST['input'];
//$input = 'video';
echo $input;
echo $page;
echo $start;
echo $per_page;

// protect against sql injection and ignore multiple spaces in the input
$keywords = preg_split('#\s+#', mysql_real_escape_string($input));

// query the database by user input title
$by_title = "LOWER(`V_TITLE`) LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `V_TITLE` Like '%", $keywords) . "%'";

$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from upload WHERE $by_title LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $msg .= '<a href="view.php?id=' . $row['V_ID'] . '"><img src="images/link_pic.png" alt="error" width="164" height="128"></a>' . '<li>Title: <b>' . $row['V_TITLE'] . '</b></br> Uploaded by: ' . $row['V_USERNAME'] . '</br>Date added: ' . $row['V_DATE'] . '</li></br></br>';
}

 $msg = "<div class='data' style='margin-bottom:10px'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data

/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM upload";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the   loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
  $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
  if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
      $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
  else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
      $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
      $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
  } else {
      $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
  }
} else {
  $start_loop = 1;
  if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
      $end_loop = 7;
  else
      $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/*     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
   $pre = $cur_page - 1;
   $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
   $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

   if ($cur_page == $i)
       $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
   else
       $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

 // TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
   $nex = $cur_page + 1;
   $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
   $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

echo $msg;

// de-allocate memory that was used to store the query results returned by mysql_query(), improve performance
mysql_free_result($query_pag_data);
}
```

Comment: Why does your function accept a parameter you're not passing in?

Comment: Does search_videos.php do what it should? Do you get a javascript error?  Why are you switching from page 1 to 2? Shouldn't this function just dynamically load the videos into your container element?

Comment: No errors, search_videos.php does what it's supposed to. However, I noticed that it always shows pages 1 and 2 even if I only have 1 video. @cale_b

Comment: @PRPGFerret I am new to AJAX, this is first time I've ever used it. Can you help me identify the mistake?

Comment: What comes back in the response from the JS?

Comment: @allen213 I have updated the question with an image of results

Comment: Data from your console would be much more helpful than a screenshot

Comment: I looked into it and seems the query is not being issued, I cannot identify any POST request. What can the problem be? Thanks @allen213

Comment: TypeError: $.cookie is not a function and TypeError: Value does not implement interface MouseEvent. @allen213. Will update with a screenshot in a sec.

Comment: @allen213 Updated the post with errors from console.

Comment: have you included the jquery cookie plugin?

Comment: click the + in the firebug console,select response from the tabs that you will then see. This will give you the response from search_videos.php

Comment: I've included the cookie plugin. Now the only error comes when I press search button "TypeError: Value does not implement interface MouseEvent." Updated the post with POST results, I will add the raw data as well. @allen213

Comment: @allen213 Post Updated... Thank you for your help, can you point why this doesn't work?

Comment: The resaponse looks sort of ok, We would need to see the php code from search_videos.php I'm afraid

Comment: @allen213 code for search_video.php has been updated to the post question.

Comment: I'm a little busy at the minute, maybe someone else will be able to help now. The key to solving this is in search_video.php. it was unlikely anyone had enough relevant information until you posted that.

Comment: OK, thank you @allen213 If you ever have the time, would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the javascript. The pagination is given by the ajax response and it seems that in some cases (or all; I didn't study the issue that deep) javascript events can't be fired after the elements to which they were bound are dynamically added to the page. The very easy to use live() method is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. What worked now was:

```
$('#container').on('click','.pagination li.active', function(){//... the ajax request here}
```

The difference between live() and on() is that the element to which you would normally bind the event is the second argument of the on() method and the on() method is called on the parent of the element.